# Getting Whatsapp messages logs from Twilio

Tags: twilio

I am trying to get whatsapp messages log sent from a twilio number , but its not returning any messages logs when I specify the From parameter.

I tried the example given in the twilio help here https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-retrieve-and-modify-message-history-php

```
$messages = $twilio->messages
                   ->read([
                              "from" => "+1XXXXXXX"
                          ],
                          20
                   );
```

I can get the logs of all messages and see those whatsapp messages when I do not specify from parameter.

I did tried sending `from=> "whatsapp:+1XXXXXX"`  but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by looking into the developer console while accessing logs on twilio dashboard. Somehow when sending the request via the SDK with

`from=> "whatsapp:+1XXXXXX"`
doesn't returned anything. I did curl and it worked. I just had to url encode  `whatsapp:+1XXXXXX` while sending request.